# Requesting and Displaying FB Information Across Multiple Views

Tags: objective-c, xcode, facebook

I'm currently getting to grips with the Facebook framework for Xcode.

So far I've managed to set everything up and log in via my application. After the user presses the login button and authenticates, the screen hides the button and instead shows the user's name and profile picture. This is exactly what I need.

Now I'm working on implementing a hidden side menu (also currently working) that will display the user's name and profile picture just like before. However I'm not sure how to get a hold of that information again.

For clarity, here is my relevant code;

**Initial Login Page - Displaying Profile Picture**

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{

self.fbProfilePicView.hidden = false;
self.fbProfilePicView.profileID = user.objectID;

}
```

**Menu View Display Attempt - Blank Image, Errors = "Use of undeclared identifier 'user' "**

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

self.menuProfilePic.profileID = user.objectID;

}
```

Does anyone know how to use already displayed data like this?

Answer (score 0):

Ok to anyone who may find this while searching for a similar issue.

When fetching data you can do it the way I posted above, like this :

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{


//CODE TO EXECUTE 


}
```

This is the function that you use after an approved authentication, because it's fed information from the login process.

To fetch information AFTER already being approved you can use something like the following:

```
//Verify User is Logged In
if(FBSession.activeSession.isOpen){

    //Start Request for User's Information
    [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error){

        //Code to Execute
        if(!error){

            //CODE TO EXECUTE

        }

    }];

}
```

In both instances you can display fetched data simply by defining properties in your view.h file and then filling them in with your view.m :

**VIEW.H**

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *uiLabel;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *fbProfilePicView;
```

**VIEW.M** *- Inside where I wrote "CODE TO EXECUTE"*

```
self.uiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:[user name]];

self.fbProfilePicView.profileID = user.objectID;
```

I hope that I've written this in an easy to understand way. I was quite stuck with this so I'm sure someone would benefit from this.